# Extract Information from multiple lines using AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to extract different details from multiple lines using `awk`.
However I fail to run a test and also print the resulting output in one line.

The information is located in different blocks and then I need to extract details inside the block..

```
awk '
     TRA TRB TRC
     /EKYC/{for(i=1; i<10; i++)
              {   (getline p )
                  if ( match(p,"TRA")) { print substr(p,4)}
                  if ( match(p,"TRB")) { print substr(p,4)}
                  if ( match(p,"TRC")) { print substr(p,4)}
              }
           }
    ' inputfile
```

The block EKYC will be there and the codes TRA TRB TRC will be located in between the EKYC blocks.

Sample text file is like below::

```
EKYC
TRA    onlyThisTRA1
TRB    onlyThisTRB1
THR    notThis
EKYC
TRA    onlyThisTRA2
TRB    onlyThisTRB2
TRC    onlyThisTRC2
EKYC
NOT
TRA    onlyThisTRA3
YEH    not this
TRC    onlyThisTRC3
```

Desired output.. in one line per block

```
onlyThisTRA1 onlyThisTRA2 null
onlyThisTRA2 onlyThisTRB2 onlyThisTRC2
onlyThisTRA3 null         onlyThisTRC3
```

Comment: If you're ever considering using `getline` make sure to read and fully understand http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first as it's rarely the best approach (or even an adequate one) and has many caveats/gotchas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk '/EKYC/{if (tra != "null") print tra, trb, trc; tra=trb=trc="null"; next}
$1=="TRA"{tra=$2} $1=="TRB"{trb=$2} $1=="TRC"{trc=$2}
END{print tra, trb, trc}' file

onlyThisTRA1 onlyThisTRB1 null
onlyThisTRA2 onlyThisTRB2 onlyThisTRC2
onlyThisTRA3 null onlyThisTRC3
```

Comment: yeah it did work out. unfortunately, i forgot to ask how to stop after first match only..? Because TRC can be found more than twice inside EKYC block and i need only the first match.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk multi dimensional arrays:

```
awk '/EKYC/ { cnt++;cnt1=0 } $0 != "EKYC" { cnt1++;if ($2 ~ "not") { $2 = "null" } dat[cnt,cnt1]=$2 } END { for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++) { for (p=1;p<=cnt1;p++) { printf "%s\t",dat[i,p] } print "" } }' filename
```

Set increment cnt when EKYC is seen and re-initialise cnt1. Use the counters to create and array of data storing the second space deliited piece of data. Finally loop through the multi-dimensional array to print the data.

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'function pr(a){ 
         n="null"; tra=a["TRA"]; trb=a["TRB"]; trc=a["TRC"]; 
         printf "%s %s %s\n",(tra)? tra:n,(trb)? trb:n,(trc)? trc:n; delete a 
     }
     /EKYC/{ if(f){ pr(a); f=0 } }
     /^TR[ABC]/{ a[$1]=$2; f=1 }END{ pr(a) }' file
```

The output:

```
onlyThisTRA1 onlyThisTRB1 null
onlyThisTRA2 onlyThisTRB2 onlyThisTRC2
onlyThisTRA3 null onlyThisTRC3
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have name-to-value pairs as you have in your data, the best approach is to first create an array capturing that mapping (`n2v[]` below) and then you can just reference the values by their names:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN  { OFS="\t" }
/EKYC/ { prt(); next }
       { n2v[$1] = $2 }
END    { prt() }
function prt() { if (length(n2v)) print v("TRA"), v("TRB"), v("TRC"); delete n2v }
function v(n)  { return (n in n2v ? n2v[n] : "null") }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
onlyThisTRA1    onlyThisTRB1    null
onlyThisTRA2    onlyThisTRB2    onlyThisTRC2
onlyThisTRA3    null    onlyThisTRC3
```

Notice with the above that the names you're interested in each appear exactly once in either upper or lower case and there are no variables named based on the values in your data so if you need to add a new name you want to get printed (e.g. "THC") then you just add `, v("THC")` inside the prt() function, and it only specifies the default `null` value in one place so if you want a different default or a different algorithm for determining the default then you just change the `v()` function.

It would actually be trivial to modify the script to accept a list of names to be printed on the command line:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN  { OFS="\t" }
/EKYC/ { prt(); next }
       { val=$0; sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"",val); n2v[$1] = val }
END    { prt() }
function prt(       nameList,nameNr,numNames) {
    if (length(n2v)) {
        numNames = split(names,nameList)
        for (nameNr=1; nameNr <= numNames; nameNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", v(nameList[nameNr]), (nameNr<numNames ? OFS : ORS)
        }
        delete n2v
    }
}
function v(n)  { return (n in n2v ? n2v[n] : "null") }

$ awk -v names='TRA TRB TRC' -f tst.awk file
onlyThisTRA1    onlyThisTRB1    null
onlyThisTRA2    onlyThisTRB2    onlyThisTRC2
onlyThisTRA3    null    onlyThisTRC3

$ awk -v names='TRA THR TRC YEH' -f tst.awk file
onlyThisTRA1    notThis null    null
onlyThisTRA2    null    onlyThisTRC2    null
onlyThisTRA3    null    onlyThisTRC3    not this
```

Note that I modified the way that `n2v[]` is populated in that second script to allow for spaces to occur after your name value since your `YEH` value (which I'm now printing above) has a space in it. If there are no spaces then that change isn't required and if the separator is tab then you can just set `FS="\t"` in the BEGIN section and then again you don't need that modification.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic explanation. I am not that much competent with AWK, I need to match only the first items. Meaning if TRA,TRB,TRC occur at any point within EKYC block should not be considered.. How can i achieve that..?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean but try changing `{ n2v[$1] = $2 }` to test if it's already been populated first `!($1 in n2v){ n2v[$1] = $2 }` and if that doesn't do what you want then update your question to clarify your requirements and add a better example.